# Module instance methods and Module "regular" methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out the true difference between a **module's instance methods** and a **module's "regular" methods**.

To do that I fired up an `irb` and did the following:

```
>> Kernel.instance_methods
>> Kernel.methods
```

I noticed that the output between these two is different.

For example, `Kernel.methods` includes a method `:readline` while `Kernel.instance_methods` does not.

Why and how is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: `methods` returns module methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might clarify things:

```
▶ module Test
▷   def im; end
▷   def mm; end
▷   module_function :mm
▷ end  
▶ Test.methods(false) # false to not output inherited
#⇒ [
#    [0] mm() Test
# ]
▶ Test.instance_methods(false) # false to not output inherited
#⇒ [
#    [0] :im
# ]
▶ Test.im
#⇒ NoMethodError: undefined method `im' for Test:Module
#     from (pry):99:in `__pry__'
▶ Test.mm
#⇒ nil # fine, called
```

Module methods might be called as is, as seen above. For instance methods, one needs an instance:

```
▶ "Hello world!".extend(Test).im
#⇒ nil # fine, called
```

Answer (score 0):

you can reference the Ruby Help file(https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html), there is words about module Kernel:

> "The Kernel module is included by class Object, so its methods are
>   available in every Ruby object."

Kernel.methods includes all Kernel.instance_methods's methods, you can try this code to verify it:

```
p Kernel.instance_methods&Kernel.methods == Kernel.instance_methods
```

in my opinion, Kernel.instance_methods can be called by any objects you created, but some of Kernel.methods can't be called by objects(like the Array/ String/ Hash).

Comment: The fact, that `Kernel.methods` also includes `Kernel.instance_methods` is a coincidence. That is because `Kernel` extends self.

Comment: It is because `Kernel` is an instance of `Module`, which is a subclass of `Object`, which mixes in `Kernel`. `Kernel` does not `extend self`, it doesn't need to because it already is an instance of itself anyway.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag, 
the methods belong to Kernel.methods, but not belong to Kernel.instance_methods, what's the motivation to define them? 
I know the "main" object cannot call some methods directly, like the "Array/ String/ Hash", we cannot do like this "self.Array(1..5)", but can do like this "Array(1..5)". But for the reason, i'm still not very clear.
could you help state it? Thanks!